# How should you read a 2D integer array?

Tags: python, list, file

I'm new to python. I would like to read a 2D integer array from a text file, one row per line in the file, the numbers separated by commas. This works:

```
s = f.read()
ss = s.splitlines()
mx = []
for i in range(0,len(ss)):
    mx.append([])
    for s1 in ss[i].split(','):
        mx[i].append(int(s1))
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a nested list comprehension:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    mx = [[int(x) for x in line.split(',')] for line in f]
```

or list comprehension with `map`:

```
mx = [map(int, line.split(',')) for line in f]
```

Note that in Python 3 you'll need an extra `list()` call around `map`.

If [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) is available:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> mx = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=',', dtype=int).tolist()
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a built-in module for reading comma-separated files ([`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)):

```
import csv
mx = [map(int, row) for row in csv.reader(open(filename))]
```

Also, if you are planning to do math with this array, you might find it useful to install and use [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/):

```
import numpy
mx = numpy.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=',', dtype=int)
```

`mx` will now be an [`array`](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-c5f4ceae0ab4b1313de41aba9104d0d7648e35cc) rather than a list of lists.